# Can I retake and send GRE scores again to schools in the US if I had already sent them before (when I took the test last time)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

After the GRE, there is an option of sending the test scores to 4 schools without paying any fee.

I had taken GRE before, and I have sent those scores to 4 schools previously. However, I am planning to take the test again, and I wanted to know if I can send the new test scores to the same 4 schools.

If I do this, which scores would those schools select? Also, how can I know if those schools received the new scores?

Additionally, it would be great if someone explains how does the schools know that the GRE scores sent belongs to a particular person.

Comment: From https://www.ets.org/gre/score-users/scores/receive-scores.html - "What information do score reports include?
For all score delivery methods, score reports include the test taker's GRE scores, mailing address, email address, phone number, date of birth, gender and intended graduate major."

Comment: From https://www.ets.org/gre/test-takers/general-test/scores/send-scores.html#accordion-d35ebe9746-item-97d8af100c - "On test day, after viewing your scores at the test center, you can choose not to send your scores at this time OR you can select either option below for each of your four FREE score reports:

Most Recent — Send your scores from your current test administration.
All — Send your scores from all GRE General Test administrations in the last 5 years."

Answer (score 1):

Admission to programs in the US is in general up to the university. (Sometimes there are state mandates for undergraduate admission.) Each university can set their own rules, so that you have to approach the universities you are applying to individually. Ph.D. admission committees in general assume that GRE scores have a large variability, so they would tend to allow you to retake the exam and submit a better score.

You also have (thanks to Jon Custer) the option to select how to treat GRE scores right after knowing the scores.